# Get node's name when click on a graphic node

Tags: c#, wpf, graphviz

I am now working with dotviewer project. I try to get node's name when user click on a node.
Refer dotviewer project here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18870/Dot2WPF-a-WPF-control-for-viewing-Dot-graphs

I detect when user click on a node, that node is highlighted by below code

```
void MouseLeftButtonDownHandler(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ToolTipController.Hide();

    // Retreive the coordinates of the mouse button event.
    Point pt = e.GetPosition(this);
    DrawingVisual hit = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, pt).VisualHit as DrawingVisual;
    if (hit != null)
    {
        string tag = hit.ReadLocalValue(FrameworkElement.TagProperty) as string;
        if (tag != null)
        {
            foreach (DrawingVisual v in _graph.Children)
            {
                v.BitmapEffect = null;
            }
            OuterGlowBitmapEffect glow = new OuterGlowBitmapEffect();
            glow.GlowColor = Colors.Blue;
            glow.GlowSize = 1;
            glow.Opacity = 0.8;
            glow.Freeze();
            hit.BitmapEffect = glow;
        }
    }
}
```

Code use "hit" to get "licked node" object and then hightlight it

[image]

But now I would get node's name (i.e A and B in picture). Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Have you checked what `sender` is?

Comment: sender is this current class (class Rodemeyer.Visualizing.GraphElement) which i can't find anything like a name attribute

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution to solve my problem.

```
string abc = hit.GetValue(FrameworkElement.TagProperty).ToString();
MessageBox.Show(abc);
```

So the full source code like below

```
void MouseLeftButtonDownHandler(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ToolTipController.Hide();

    // Retreive the coordinates of the mouse button event.
    Point pt = e.GetPosition(this);
    DrawingVisual hit = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, pt).VisualHit as DrawingVisual;

    string abc = hit.GetValue(FrameworkElement.TagProperty).ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(abc);

    if (hit != null)
    {
        string tag = hit.ReadLocalValue(FrameworkElement.TagProperty) as string;
        if (tag != null)
        {
            foreach (DrawingVisual v in _graph.Children)
            {
                v.BitmapEffect = null;
            }
            OuterGlowBitmapEffect glow = new OuterGlowBitmapEffect();
            glow.GlowColor = Colors.Blue;
            glow.GlowSize = 1;
            glow.Opacity = 0.8;
            glow.Freeze();
            hit.BitmapEffect = glow;
        }
    }
}
```